# Updating date values based on number of days between startdate and enddate

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have the following table and I need to re-calculate the `StartDate` based on some business rules that I was given.  Specifically, when the `StartDate` of the succeeding session is within one calendar day (i.e., < 2 days) the sessions are combined, using the earlier `StartDate` and the later `EndDate`.

| StartDate | EndDate | DaysBetweenSessions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2011-04-15 | 2011-04-21 | 3 |
| 2011-04-24 | 2011-04-27 | 3 |
| 2011-04-30 | 2011-05-01 | 0 |
| 2011-05-01 | 2011-05-06 | 5 |
| 2011-05-11 | 2011-05-15 | 1 |
| 2011-05-16 | 2011-05-17 | 0 |
| 2011-05-17 | 2011-05-25 | 10 |

What I need as a result:

| StartDate | EndDate | DaysBetweenSessions | NewStartDate | NewEndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011-04-15 | 2011-04-21 | 3 | 2011-04-15 | 2011-04-21 |
| 2011-04-24 | 2011-04-27 | 3 | 2011-04-24 | 2011-04-27 |
| 2011-04-30 | 2011-05-01 | 0 | 2011-04-30 | 2011-05-06 |
| 2011-05-01 | 2011-05-06 | 5 | 2011-04-30 | 2011-05-06 |
| 2011-05-11 | 2011-05-15 | 1 | 2011-05-11 | 2011-05-25 |
| 2011-05-16 | 2011-05-17 | 0 | 2011-05-11 | 2011-05-25 |
| 2011-05-17 | 2011-05-25 | 10 | 2011-05-11 | 2011-05-25 |

I have attempted to use `df.shift` to get the `PreviousStartDate, PreviousEndDate, NextStartDate, NextEndDate`, and then tried to loop through the dataset with `df.iterrows()`, calculating the new dates, but I run into a technical issue that I don't fully understand - while in the loop that was used to update a value, I cannot use an operator on that new value - the new value hasn't been written to the df yet.

Comment: I'm looking for fewer than 2 days - question updated, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `groupby` and `tranform`:

```
#convert to datetime if necessary
df["StartDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["StartDate"])
df["EndDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["EndDate"])

df["NewStartDate"] = df.groupby((df["DaysBetweenSessions"]>=2).cumsum().shift().fillna(0))["StartDate"].transform("min")
df["NewEndDate"] = df.groupby((df["DaysBetweenSessions"]>=2).cumsum().shift().fillna(0))["EndDate"].transform("max")

>>> df
  StartDate    EndDate  DaysBetweenSessions NewStartDate NewEndDate
0 2011-04-15 2011-04-21                    3   2011-04-15 2011-04-21
1 2011-04-24 2011-04-27                    3   2011-04-24 2011-04-27
2 2011-04-30 2011-05-01                    0   2011-04-30 2011-05-06
3 2011-05-01 2011-05-06                    5   2011-04-30 2011-05-06
4 2011-05-11 2011-05-15                    1   2011-05-11 2011-05-25
5 2011-05-16 2011-05-17                    0   2011-05-11 2011-05-25
6 2011-05-17 2011-05-25                   10   2011-05-11 2011-05-25
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This definitely seems to work.  Can you explain the purpose of the ```shift()``` in this case? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Just run `df["DaysBetweenSessions"]>=2).cumsum()` and see the output. It doesn't align with the groups you want.