# Pandas cumsum on a groupby object with a boolean condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, cumsum

For the given dataset below, I am able to calculate "distinct" visits to a hotel, which is defined as any visit where the traveler arrives at least one full calendar day (i.e., 2 or more days) since a previous departure.  Any arrival that is less than one full calendar day since the previous visit will be merged with the previous visit.  The negative `days_between_visits` are simulating some data errors that are found throughout the dataset.

I get the new start date by running: `df["NewStartDate"] = df.groupby((df["days_between_visits"]>=2).cumsum().shift().fillna(0))["arrival_date "].transform("min")`

and get the new end date by running: `df["NewEndDate"] = df.groupby((df["days_between_visits"]>=2).cumsum().shift().fillna(0))["departure_date "].transform("max")`

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69094711/updating-date-values-based-on-number-of-days-between-startdate-and-enddate) for additional info on `NewStartDate` and `NewEndDate` were calculated.

| ID | arrival_date | departure_date | days_between_visits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010-04-01 | 2010-04-02 | 0 |
| 1 | 2010-04-02 | 2010-04-02 | 1 |
| 1 | 2010-04-03 | 2010-04-03 | 1 |
| 1 | 2010-04-04 | 2010-04-04 | 1 |
| 1 | 2010-04-05 | 2010-04-05 | 15 |
| 1 | 2010-04-20 | 2010-04-21 | -1 |
| 1 | 2010-04-20 | 2010-04-22 | -2 |
| 1 | 2010-04-20 | 2010-04-27 | 39 |
| 1 | 2010-06-05 | 2010-06-05 | 1 |
| 1 | 2010-06-06 | 2010-06-06 | 2 |
| 1 | 2010-06-08 | 2010-09-22 | 375 |
| 1 | 2011-10-01 | 2011-10-02 | 0 |
| 1 | 2011-10-02 | 2011-10-04 | 1 |
| 1 | 2011-10-05 | 2011-10-06 | 87 |
| 1 | 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-02 |  |

**The problem:** I don't understand what is happening on the conditional `groupby` with the `.cumsum()`.  The conditional `groupby` (on its own) returns two groups (i.e., those with <2 days between visits (i.e., `False` group) and those with >=2 days between visits (i.e., `True` group).  When adding the `.cumsum()` to the process, we get a cumulative sum on the `days_between_visits` within each group **BUT** only after new groups are created, which are split where the condition in the `groupby` is `True` (i.e., each row where `days_between_visits >= 2` is the start of a new group).  Can somebody explain what is happening here and why the `.cumsum()` is resulting in more groups?

Final result:

| ID | arrival_date | departure_date | days_between_visits | NewStartDate | NewEndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010-04-01 | 2010-04-02 | 0 | 2010-04-01 | 2010-04-05 |
| 1 | 2010-04-02 | 2010-04-02 | 1 | 2010-04-01 | 2010-04-05 |
| 1 | 2010-04-03 | 2010-04-03 | 1 | 2010-04-01 | 2010-04-05 |
| 1 | 2010-04-04 | 2010-04-04 | 1 | 2010-04-01 | 2010-04-05 |
| 1 | 2010-04-05 | 2010-04-05 | 15 | 2010-04-01 | 2010-04-05 |
| 1 | 2010-04-20 | 2010-04-21 | -1 | 2010-04-20 | 2010-04-27 |
| 1 | 2010-04-20 | 2010-04-22 | -2 | 2010-04-20 | 2010-04-27 |
| 1 | 2010-04-20 | 2010-04-27 | 39 | 2010-04-20 | 2010-04-27 |
| 1 | 2010-06-05 | 2010-06-05 | 1 | 2010-06-05 | 2010-06-06 |
| 1 | 2010-06-06 | 2010-06-06 | 2 | 2010-06-05 | 2010-06-06 |
| 1 | 2010-06-08 | 2010-09-22 | 375 | 2010-06-08 | 2010-09-22 |
| 1 | 2011-10-01 | 2011-10-02 | 0 | 2011-10-01 | 2011-10-06 |
| 1 | 2011-10-02 | 2011-10-04 | 1 | 2011-10-01 | 2011-10-06 |
| 1 | 2011-10-05 | 2011-10-06 | 87 | 2011-10-01 | 2011-10-06 |
| 1 | 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-02 |  | 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-02 |

Comment: hi, interesting, might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61342916/groupby-cumulative-sum-in-pandas-based-on-specific-condition

Comment: hi @jspcal, thanks for the response.  I hadn't considered using a function, but if I can't get some clarity on the current approach, I might have to explore that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do this piece by piece: `(df["days_between_visits"]>=2)` returns a boolean series.  We treat this series as an int64 because `pandas` allows for some integer operations to be performed on boolean series (`with False == 0` and `True == 1`).

[image]

When we perform the `.cumsum()` on the boolean series, we get the following:

[image]

However, because the `True` values are indications of the last row for a given visit to the hotel (i.e., >=2 days until the next visit visit), we need to include the row that contains the `True` (i.e., `1`) value into the visit by shifting (i.e., `shift()`) the data down one row producing the following:

[image]

Now we can `fillna(0)` and we have our distinct groups.  We can now groupby this newly created series and perform our transform functions on the `arrival_date` and `departure_date` as needed.